# My question was already asked, but its accepted answer doesn’t suit me

Tags: discussion, duplicates

I have a question I’d like to ask — and it turns out to be pretty much an exact duplicate of [an earlier question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64750/avoid-line-breaks-after-lstinline), except with a very slightly different example.  (Specifically, the difference is just that my inline code fragments are single identifiers, not multiple words.)

However, the accepted (and only) answer there isn’t exactly an answer; it’s a workaround for how to prevent the problem arising, and in my case, this workaround doesn’t work.

What should I do?  Re-ask the question, with a note “this is not quite an exact duplicate of [this existing question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64750/avoid-line-breaks-after-lstinline), because… ”?  Offer a bounty, with explanatory comment, to encourage further answers to the older question?  Something else I haven’t thought of?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [I've just been told I have to post a follow-up question, why and how?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117/5764)

Answer (score 31):

If you can show with a good MWE that the apparent duplicate answer doesn't work, it's completely fine to ask a new question, clearly linking to the other question and with the new MWE to show how that answer doesn't work for you.